# 405 method not allowed, Django + ngrok, only on my local machine

Tags: python, django, http, debugging, ngrok

This is a legacy project that I'm working with other guys in my current job.
and is doing a very strange behavior that I cannot understand.

It's returning 405 http response status, which does not make sense, because this view already accepts POST requests
[image]

I would share a couple of snippets, I just detected that happens just in the comment that I would mark.

this is the view file, that actually accepts both methods GET and POST

```
@csrf_exempt
@load_checkout
@validate_cart
@validate_is_shipping_required
@require_http_methods(["GET", "POST"])
def one_step_view(request, checkout):
    """Display the entire checkout in one step."""
```

this is the decorator that modifies the response, and returns 405.

```
def load_checkout(view):
    """Decorate view with checkout session and cart for each request.
    Any views decorated by this will change their signature from
    `func(request)` to `func(request, checkout, cart)`."""
    @wraps(view)
    @get_or_empty_db_cart(Cart.objects.for_display())
    def func(request, cart):
        try:
            session_data = request.session[STORAGE_SESSION_KEY]
        except KeyError:
            session_data = ''
        tracking_code = analytics.get_client_id(request)

        checkout = Checkout.from_storage(
            session_data, cart, request.user, tracking_code)

        response = view(request, checkout, cart)  # in this response it returns 405. 
        if checkout.modified:
            request.session[STORAGE_SESSION_KEY] = checkout.for_storage()
        return response

    return func
```

Any idea or clue when I can start to find out the problem?.

for the record: I didn't code this, this was working a couple of days ago, and its just happening in my local environment, on stage and production, and even the local of others developers are working just fine. I have all the requirements and the dependencies, and are updated.

BTW I'm using ngrok for tunneling
[image]

--[image]

[image]

Comment: What function is actually being called as `view`?  Can you step into that function with the debugger to see why it is returning 405?  (I assume it's not `one_step_view()` because that function only takes two arguments, but you're calling `view()` with three arguments.)

Comment: yeap, it is one_step_view(). I would edit and add it to the question

Answer (score -1):

if your front-end use different HOST && PORT
you need to add CROS  in Django app